# My ESP32 is scanning all the nearby WiFi Networks but it does not connect to my WiFi Router using Arduino IDE (Return Value of WiFi.status API = 6)

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp32, arduino-ide, esp8266wifi

I am trying to connect my ESP32 to my Wifi Router using Arduino IDE but it is not connecting & giving a connection failed or disconnected status. I also confirmed it is scanning all the available Wifi Networks but not connecting to my router. I even tried with another ESP32 board but the problem is still there.

```
I tried this code below. This code would scan/give the available Wifi networks and it did. Also, I was expecting this code to run smoothly but my ESP32 won't connect to my Wifi router.
```

```
#include<WiFi.h>

const char *ssid = "my_SSID";  
const char *password = "my_Password";

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(2000);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.disconnect();
    delay(100);

    Serial.println("scan start");

    // WiFi.scanNetworks will return the number of networks found
    int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
    Serial.println("scan done");
    if (n == 0) {
        Serial.println("no networks found");
    } else {
        Serial.print(n);
        Serial.println(" networks found");}

    // Connect to my network.
    WiFi.begin(ssid,password);     

    // Check Status of your WiFi Connection
    int x = WiFi.status(); // If x=3 (Connected to Network) & If x=6 (Disconnected from Network)
    Serial.print("WiFi Connection Status is ");
    Serial.println(x);
    
    while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(1000);
        Serial.println("WiFi Connection Failed...");
        WiFi.disconnect();
        WiFi.reconnect();  }

    //Print local IP address and start web server
      Serial.println("\nConnecting");
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
      Serial.println("ESP32 IP address: ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {}
```

[1st image shows the output of my serial monitor. 2nd inamge shows the return value for WiFi.status function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgjUN.jpg)

Comment: WiFi.begin doesn't block until the esp joined the AP.  of course it is disconnected (code 6) before it is connected (WL_CONNECTED). but you don't let it connect with that `disconnect()` call. see the examples.

Comment: Yes Juraj, you are right. Its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
#include<WiFi.h>

const char *ssid = "YourSSID";  
const char *password = "YourPassword";
        
void initWiFi() {
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
      Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi ..");
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print('.');
        delay(1000);
      }
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    }
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(115200);
      initWiFi();
      Serial.print("RRSI: ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.RSSI());
    }
    
    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    }
```

Comment: a basic example from the library

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this same issue. I found that, for me, the issue was not in the ESP32. It was the WiFi Router. I had the security on the router set to 'WEP' in the router. When I changed the security to 'WPA2-PSK' the ESP32 device connected right away.